# code generating segmentation fault when run with -m32 flag

Tags: c

I have a function that runs perfectly in a 64 bit address space, but when compiled with the -m32 flag it produces a segmentation fault. I have no idea why this could be happening. Any help is appreciated.

```
int* getNextVPage(int n){
  int i; int cont = 0; int x; int y;
  for(i = 0; i < PD_SIZE; i++){
    int j;
    for( j = 0; j < PT_SIZE; j++)
      if(vBit[i][j] == 0){
        if(cont == 0){x = i; y = j;}              // finds n continuous free pages and returns the first one in the the sequence
        cont++;
        if(cont == n){
          int l;
          for(l = 0; l < n; l++){
            vBit[x][y+l] = 1;
          }
          int* ret = (int*) malloc(2*sizeof(int)); ret[0] = x; ret[1] = y;
          return ret;
        }
      }
      else{
        cont = 0;
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal complete program. Could your `_SIZE` macros be related to 32/64?

Comment: What happens if the outer loop ends, what do you return then? Doesn't the compiler complain about possible not returning a value? Perhaps you should enable more verbose warnings (like e.g. `-Wall` and `-Wextra` and perhaps even `-pedantic`)?

Comment: Guessing here, since some pieces are missing, but I note that `y == j`, so `y+1` may equal `PT_SIZE`, which may be out of bounds for the array `vBit`.

Comment: @kabanus they are just numbers. 4096 for both the way I'm running it now

Comment: @500 - Internal Server Error The way vBit is defined, that cannot be the case. However, why would that change depending on the size of the address space?

Comment: @Some programmer dude Yes, that's an issue with the code. But I don't see how that could be related to the issues with the size of the address space

Comment: Are the continuous free pages you find allowed to cross row boundaries in `vBit`? If not, the termination condition for the inner loop ought to be `j < PT_SIZE - n`.

Comment: Well it could be relevant depending on where the crash happens. If you let the function end without returning something, and then attempt to use the returned pointer, you will have *undefined behavior*. And UB with pointers very often leads to crashes. You really should spend some time [learning how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). And treat any warning the compiler give you as an error, and fix it.